# Android: better way to get an integer from a spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, arrays

I have a spinner filled with integer values, and I'm trying to extract the selected value. I managed to do with the following line of code:

```
Integer.decode(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
```

but this seems like a lot of calls for what should be a simple operation.

I'm creating the spinner using a string-array defined as follows:

In the strings.xml

```
<string-array name="settings_cells_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</string-array>
```

In the activity onCreate function:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.num_cells_spinner);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.settings_cells_array, R.layout.my_layout);

// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_layout);

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In my mind, since the spinner is created with a string-array, the `.toString()` call seems excessive, but I imagine that's leaving room for flexibility with adapters and spinners built out of custom objects or something fancy like that.

Anyway, my question is this:
is there a better way to extract an integer from a spinner defined this way, or alternatively, is there a better way to set up my spinner such that it plays more nicely with **int**s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is first getting the array from the resources, then create an Integer array and give it to an `ArrayAdapter<Integer>` instead. Something like this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.num_cells_spinner);
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settings_cells_array);

Integer[] intArray = new Integer[array.length];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
}

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, intArray);

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then just cast the result of `getSelectedItem()` to `Integer` :

```
Integer i = (Integer)spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: That makes good sense and seems more efficient than what I was trying to do. Thanks!